# Cleaning up text: from ALLCAPS to <em>allcaps</em>

Tags: html, regex, notepad++

I need to clean up some text for html that used ALLCAPS instead of italics. So I'd like to take something that looks like this:

```
Here is an artificial EXAMPLE of a piece of TEXT that
uses allcaps as a way of EMPHASIZING words.
```

And convert it into this:

```
Here is an artificial <em>example</em> of a piece of <em>text</em> that
uses allcaps as a way of <em>emphasizing</em> words.
```

I'm tagging this with regex and notepad++, but (as you can probably tell) I don't know the first thing about how to use them.

Answer (score 2):

There're no such possibilities with Notepad++ regex engine.

You can run a script that do the job, in Perl for example:

```
perl -pi.back -e "s#\b([A-Z]+)\b#'<em>'.lc($1).'</em>'/eg" yourfile.html
```

`yourfile.html` will be saved in `yourfile.html.back`

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know anything about Perl.

Comment: @76987: too bad :-( I don't see another way than a script to do the job. But it's not so hard to install perl. I guess you're under windows, have a look at http://strawberryperl.com/

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do this using JavaScript's string replace method:

```
var capfix = function (x) {
    var emout = function (y) {
        y = y.charAt(0) + "<em>" + y.toLowerCase() + "</em>" + y.charAt(y.length - 1);
    };
    return x.replace(/\s[A-Z]\s/g, emout);
};
```

To execute just call:

```
capfix(yourData);
```

This assumes that "yourData" is just a variable that represents your data as a string.  If you wanted to use a web tool then "yourData" could represent the value from some input control, as in the following:

```
var yourData = document.getElementById("myinput").value;
alert(capfix(yourData));
```

To make that work just put an id attribute on your web tool input such as:

```
<textarea id="myinput"></textarea>
```

Comment: I really have no idea how to use JavaScript, much less apply it to a text file.

Comment: This will replace `AbC` by `<em>a</em>b<em>c</em>`. I'm not sure that is the OP wants.

Comment: Good catch, M42.  Code is modified.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I konw the [regex engine](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Regular_Expressions) of Notepad++ is not advanced enough to do this.

I would advice to use a programming language to accomplish this, in PHP for example you could do this:

```
echo preg_replace_callback('/([A-Z]{2,})/', create_function('$s', 'return "<em>".strtolower($s[0])."</em>";'), $s);
```

Be sure to exclude the legitim first capital letter of a single word in the regex.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've barely even heard of PHP.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you cannot change casing in the `Find\Replace` mechanism of Notepad++.

If all you need is the `<em>` tag insertion you can do the following:
In the `Find` box type `(\s+)([A-Z]+)(\s+)`, abd in the `Replace` type `\1<em>\2</em>\3`.

You can try some of the `TextFX` tools maybe in the `TextFX Characters` sub-menu.

Comment: Thanks, but I just tried this, and it indiscriminately added the `<em>` tag to every other word.

Comment: Is the 'match case' checkbox checked?